# If $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$ is nonnegative, can we conclude $\mu( \{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} ) < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove a statement, and I need the fact that:

> If $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$  is  a nonnegative function, then this implies $\mu( \{x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} ) < \infty$.

But I don't know if this is necessarily true.

Here is my general idea for a proof that might work:

Suppose $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$ is a nonnegative function. Also, suppose by contradiction that $\mu( \{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} ) = \infty$.  If $f$ attains a minimum positive value (**there is no guarantee that $f$ behaves this way....**) then let $\alpha$ be that minimum value.  Define a simple function $s(x) = \begin{cases} \alpha & x \in \{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} \\ 0 & x \not \in \{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} \end{cases}$.

Then $0 \leq s(x) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$, and $\int \limits_{X} s(x) \,d\mu = \infty$, implying $\int \limits_{X} f \,d\mu = \infty$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$.

What if $f$ does not attain a minimum positive value (i.e., its infimum is $0$)?

Comment: Looking at examples might help... What about $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ on the real line endowed with the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Did That function is non-zero for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which means the measure of the set where this function is non-zero is infinite (all of $\mathbb{R}$).  And its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is $\pi$.  :( So I cannot use this statement which seems fundamental to what I am trying to prove.

Comment: @Did Why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at examples helps... The function $f(x)=\mathrm e^{-x^2}$ on the real line endowed with $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure shows that $f$ can be integrable while $\{f\ne0\}$ has infinite measure.